# How to describe TabSpec in XML?

Tags: android

Is there a way to describe tabs of a TabHost in XML instead of creating them with Java code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sorry, you have to define them in Java.

Comment: Do you know why there is no such feature?

Comment: @Shooshpanchick: No clue. Certainly the `setContent(View)` and the `setIndicator(CharSequence, int resourceId)` signatures would work easily enough in XML. You could write your own utility class that reads your own XML attributes and handles this. For example, put `shoosh:tabIcon` and `shoosh:tabCaption` attributes on each child of the `FrameLayout`. Then, in your utility code, load the layout as an XML resource, find the relevant `FrameLayout`, iterate over the children, and set up the tabs.

Comment: Thanks. I'll stop banging my head against the wall now trying to do it in XML.